# Which is resolved first, new obstacles or new crossfire level in Shadowrun Crossfire?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

In Shadowrun: Crossfire, you draw a new Crossfire card after each round. On it are events, which have to be resolved. If you play the Extraction mission, each round new obstacles are revealed, which may have flipped actions that have to be resolved. Which comes first, a new Crossfire card or new obstacles? The order influences the results in some situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you've got your order of play mixed up a little bit. Let's review what the order of a round is:

> 1. Draw a new Crossfire card.
> 2. Each runner takes a turn, beginning with the starting
>      runner. Play continues clockwise until everyone has taken a turn. The starting runner remains the same throughout the game.
> 3. The round is over. Repeat steps 1–3 until the game ends. (Rulebook, pg. 12)

Missions go over the course of a number of Scenes. The Extraction mission has the following rules for ending a Scene:

> **Mission Progress Track and Ending a Scene:** At the end of the Client’s turn, advance the mission-progress marker to the next round down on the track and follow the instructions for that step (see **Obstacles and Crossfire**, above, for obstacle placement). (Rulebook, pg. 20)

So a scene ends, and obstacles are drawn, immediately at the end of a Client's turn, which will happen during Step 2 of a round, and then will be followed by Step 3 when any end of round effects are resolved. A Crossfire card is then drawn during Step 1 of a round. So there will *never* be a conflict between new obstacles and new Crossfire cards because they happen during different steps of a round.

Also, if you end a turn with no obstacles (and therefore remove a Crossfire card), the [*Shadowrun: Crossfire* FAQ](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/shadowrun-crossfire-game/) clarifies that you do **not** draw a new Crossfire card immediately, so again there will never be a conflict between a Crossfire event and obstacles.

> **Q:** I’ve just ended a turn with no obstacles in play, so I remove the current *Crossfire* card from play. Now I draw another one, right?
>
> **A:** No. You only draw a new *Crossfire* card at the start of a round of play. Depending on when you removed the current *Crossfire* card, it might still be several turns before you draw a new one.